# how to make conditional loop click event with nightmare on node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, nightmare

i am tying to make web scrawler.
so i'm using node+nightmare.

the webpage that I want to crawl has 'load more' button.
when I click this button, more posts are loaded like any other webpage.

The problem is - the number of posts on this page can change. So my crawler application dont know how many times press the 'load more' button.

I know there is an 'exist' apu in nightmare,  but i want to use this repeatedly with condition, not once or fixed number loop.

Is there any logic that i can use this case?
somebody help me T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at my answer [Repeatedly Clickling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605473/repeatedly-clicking-an-element-on-a-page-using-electron-nightarejs)

You can condition in the same code as:

```
function next() {
  if(condition)
  BETHESDA.wait('div[data-is="main-mods-pager"] > button')
    .click('div[data-is="main-mods-pager"] > button')
    .then(function() {
      console.log("click done");
      next();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("All done.");
    });
}

function condition() {
  //Your condition code goes here
  //return true or false
}
```

I think this should be an duplicate question.